# Luck or skill ? Hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Blind wine tasting.

You have 4 wines to pick from.
You must identify the Cabernet.
20 trials.

Random chance says you get 25% correct (5 correctly identified)

In reality, you get 8 correct (40% correct)

How can we decide if this was skill or luck?  (p < .05)

H0:  No skill

Ha:  There is wine tasting skill

P0 = .25

x = 8

n = 20

I am only concerned with random luck above 25%, so is this 1 tailed test?

On my calc, I get p = .06.   Is that correct?
Since .06 > .05, this may have been luck.

Accept H0 (Null hypothesis)

Correct?

Comment: This problem seems to be under-specified. If there are 20 trials but only 4 wines, how are the trails allocated to wines? If you're trying to find the Cabernet, how many such wines are there among the 4 wines?

Comment: Here's a post on AndrewGelman.com about *finding* hot hands in sports...  http://andrewgelman.com/2015/07/09/hey-guess-what-there-really-is-a-hot-hand/  it's kind of background material to your question..

Answer (score 1):

$H_0$ follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $B(20, 0.25)$: twenty Bernoulli trials each with 0.25 probability of success. The probability of getting 8 or more successful trials under $H_0$ is $1 - P(N \leq 7) \approx 0.1$.